# Singleton when using MarkUpExtension

Tags: c#, class, singleton

How to create a singleton class which inherit from MarkUpExtension class?

Comment: Which language/framework/whatever? :) Need more details from you ;)

Comment: I am using C# language. I want to add custom extension in WPF. So I have created a DataExtension class to bind custom data. I want to make DataExtension class to be singleton. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html). Just add that functionality onto your class and it should work. Make sure there's no public constructor of any kind.